# PySide Frame doesn't appear on Grid Layout

Tags: python, pyside, qgridlayout, qframe

I'm trying to add a simple square to a grid layout, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
self.resultFrame = QFrame()
self.resultFrame.setGeometry(100, 200, 0, 0)
self.resultFrame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #000 }")

gridLayout.addWidget(self.resultFrame, 0, 0, 1, 4)
```

If I switch `self.resultFrame` to, for example, a `QLabel` or a `QPushButton`, it seems to work fine, but not with `QFrame`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have yo use [setFrameStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qframe.html#setFrameStyle) to define how to draw the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to make out what you could be doing wrong since we don't see the rest of the code, but at least I can confirm that this simple example draws a black frame and button inside a grid layout.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resultFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.resultFrame.setGeometry(100, 200, 0, 0)
        self.resultFrame.setStyleSheet("QFrame { background-color: #000 }")

        self.myButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self, 'test')

        gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.resultFrame, 0, 0)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.myButton, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.show()

win = MyWindow()
```

It could also be the way you use spans when using the grid layout's addWidget method with the rest of your items. For example, if I used gridLayout.addWidget(self.resultFrame, 0, 0, 1 ,4) in the code above the button will no longer be in view!